# meta name="viewport" not working as expected

Tags: html, viewport, mobile-devices

I am creating a new site. In the head I have

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- for mobile phones -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

However, on mobile devices its large and you have to scroll horizontally. i was expecting it to scale and fit into the width of the device. I have used this before on other sites and it has worked fine.

What's wrong please

Comment: This article from quirksmode.org may help: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/

Comment: oh dear - having read your material Jeff I realize that I have rather misunderstood what the the viewport meta tag was doing and my question is now redundant. Sorry :-(